# Hide only specific <td> from table row based on next class name in CSS or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am getting table rows based on certain conditions. This is my code structure

```
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>                             
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl" >Available</td>
  </tr>
```

i want to remove only that `<td>` which is just above class `esl` or in other way, remove first td when we have more than 1 td in a row. Tried `~` also in css but didn't get any success.   Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i need to remove nbsp; td of 2nd tr becuase it has more than 1 td in tr

Comment: Side note: `start` and `row` are invalid attributes for `tr` elements. If you want to store data on elements, use [the `data-` prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Comment: Just to be clear, CSS cannot *remove* elements, it can only hide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:first-child` to hide first `td` in `tr`.

Then use [:only-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) to make sure that `td` with no other sibling displays.

```css
td:first-child {
  display: none;
}

td:only-child {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbspTEST;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;TEST2</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Very nice! I had never heard of `:only-child`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only discovered it recently :)

Comment: And yet support for it is basically universal. Cool!

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want using css only

- First you hide all first cells using `:first-child`
- Then you show the last cells using `:last-child`, this is needed in the case of a unique cell which you want to be displayed

**See code snippet:**

```css
table td:first-child {
 display:none;
}

table td:last-child{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('.esl').prev().hide();
```

Comment: You *can* do this with jQuery, but there's no good reason to.

Comment: The OP tag jquery that's why i done this in jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous sibling in jquery using `prev` as described [here](https://api.jquery.com/prev/). So you can do something like this:

```
$document.ready(function() {    
    $.("es1").prev().remove() 
});
```

Comment: You *can* do this with jQuery, but there's no good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

You can you CSS or JS With CSS its like this on JS depending on what js framework you are using. Good luck!

```css
table td:only-of-type {
 display:table-cell !important;
}
table td{
 display:none;
}

.tdclass.dateclass.esl{
  display:table-cell !important;
 }
```

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
    <td class="tdclass dateclass esl">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr start="7" row="1" class="tableinsideth trmain">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table .tableinsideth').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('td').length > 1){
            $(this).find('td').first().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should explain your code and why it helps answering the question.

Comment: sorry, next time i will do as your feedback